# Microsoft Identity Web - How to get the User Signed In event?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using the Microsoft.Identity.Web NuGet package in order to sign users into Net Core 3.1 WebApp using Azure AD, then once the user has signed in, I then use their token with scopes to call the MS Graph API to fetch some additional data from their profile, such as their forename, surname, username etc. Basically some additional bits of info about the user that is not automatically included in the token returned from Azure AD.

This part work is working fine.

What I want to achieve is configuring some form of a system event or trigger to tell me when the user has successfully signed in, I would then use this trigger to run the Graph API query and fetch the user's additional profile attributes. The reason I want to do this is so each time the user requests a new page and runs a method or action, I can include their additional attributes into the logging.

Because the Microsoft.Identity.Web package hides away the Account Controller somewhere within the NuGet package (assuming a dll or something) I can't seem to access it to look at what I could latch onto in the way of an event trigger that I can use for the above.

Unless I call the MS Graph once the user has logged in then I would not have access to some of the user profile attributes that I want to include in the Serilog Logging structure.

Once I have the user attributes needed from MS Graph then I assume the best solution would be to store them in memory as getters setters for the lifetime of the logged in session, that way I can then access them from any page model / controller within the app through DI or a model.

I had thought about just simply calling the MS Graph from a OnGet() method when the home index page is loaded after a successful login, but the challenge is a user might not necessarily login by visiting the home page first, they might have saved a bookmark to another page they want to go to straight away which means the OnGet() method in the Home page might never be run. I need a more bullet proof solution given I should ensure that these extra user profile attributes are fetched every time without fail, regardless of which page is first visited that prompts the user login process.

Note: I've observed the fact that if I go straight to a page that has authorization enabled, once logged in then OIDC just returns me to that same page.

The final step in this riddle would be to remove the saved user profile attributes from memory once the user logs out, but this should be easy enough given the logout session always returns me to https://localhost:5001/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut

If anyone has any ideas on what I could work with using this library to achieve the above would be great, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something within Microsoft Identity Web, for the custom code:

> AddSignIn has another override, which takes delegates instead of a
> configuration section. The override with a configuration section
> actually calls the override with delegates. In advanced scenarios you
> might want to add configuration by code, or if you want to subscribe
> to OpenIdConnect events. For instance if you want to provide a custom
> processing when the token is validated.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apps#using-delegate-events

Here are Microsoft code samples for the ASP.net core, for many cases:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/

Comment: Thanks Luke, yep i eventually found this override info last night and have put something together now. I have also concluded another solution would be to add some additional optional claims to the ID Token when returned from Azure after successful login, just figuring that out as well at the mo.